# Cannot resolve symbol 'URL' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Why can't I use the **URL** class?
Android Studio does not find this class.
[image]

Comment: Rebuild and restart

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya have had this problem for a long time
It cannot be solved by restarting

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Which file should I add? I added build.gradle and got an error

Comment: `got an error ` ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya It was my error.I added, but it was ineffective. Should I reinstall Android Studio?

Comment: Sync project with Gradle files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215118/discussion-between-nima-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: try to View > Tool Window > Gradle > collapse project name > Tasks > build > cleanBuildCache

Comment: @Zain It didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

A :

```
 Clean Project and Rebuild
```

B:

```
Invalidate Cach and Restart AS
```

C : use java 8

```
compileOptions { 
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
}
```